# reverse recursion in F#

Tags: recursion, f#, reverse

(I am not sure about that whether reverse recursion is a correct name..)

I'd like to define a recursive function with initial value at k=n and terminate at k = 0

So I tried to write it in this way(here n = 10):

```
let rec f k =
  match k with
  |_ when k > 10 -> 0
  |  10 -> 1
  |_ -> (f n+1)-1
```

and the VS crashed. Could anyone help me?

dividing line------------------

I think my question is a little like this:

```
Consider a sequence with 
a(10) = 1 
a(k) = [a(k+1)*a(k+1)] + 1
a(k) = 0 if (k < 0 or k > 10)
```

How could I implement it in the F# ?

Comment: The function itself is not important.. I just want to know how to write a correct one with this kind of "reverse recursive" property.

Comment: Where does the n come from?

Comment: (f n+1) is same with f(n) + 1, if n < 10, it always run f(n), use f (n+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let rec f k =
  match k with
  |_ when k > 10 || k < 0 -> 0
  | 10 -> 1
  |_ -> f (k+1) * f (k+1) + 1
```